# .position autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, position

Trying to position the flip of [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) 2 pixels right of the input. The library .position gives me ability to set the values as "right", "left", ... also to add pixels like `right+1`.

But if i add the like `right-2` than the flip moves totally to left. I am not a JavaScript Code and need some help please.

This is the JavaScript Code

```
 function html_entity_decode(b){var a=document.createElement("textarea");a.innerHTML=b.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");return a.value}$.extend({getUrlVars:function(){var d=[],c;var a=window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf("?")+1).split("&");for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++){c=a[b].split("=");d.push(c[0]);d[c[0]]=c[1]}return d},getUrlVar:function(a){return $.getUrlVars()[a]}});$.widget("custom.catcomplete",$.ui.autocomplete,{_renderMenu:function(d,c){var b=this,a="";$.each(c,function(e,f){if(f.category!=a){f.category=html_entity_decode(f.category);d.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>"+f.category+"</li>");a=f.category}f.label=html_entity_decode(f.label);f.desc=html_entity_decode(f.desc);b._renderItem(d,f)})}});$(function(){$("#searchbox").catcomplete({source:function(c,a){c.term=escape(c.term);var b=$.getJSON("autocomplete.php",c,function(e,d,f){a(e)})},minLength:2,delay:200,position:{my:"right top",at:"right-2 bottom", collision:"flip horizontal"},highlight:true,select:function(b,c){var a=$.getUrlVar("XTCsid");if(a!=null){var d="?";if(c.item.link.indexOf("&")!=-1){d="&"}a=d+"XTCsid="+a}else{a=""}location.href=c.item.link+a;return false}}).data("catcomplete")._renderItem=function(b,d){var f="";if(d.desc!=null&&d.desc!=""){f="<div class='short_desc'>"+d.desc+"</div>"}var e="";if(d.image!=null&&d.image!=""){e="<div class='prod_img'><img src='"+d.image+"' /></div>"}var c="";if(d.price!=null&&d.price!=""){c="<div class='prod_preis'>"+d.price+"</div>"}var a="";if(d.label!=null&&d.label!=""){a="<div class='prod_name'>"+d.label+"</div>"}return $("<li></li>").data("item.autocomplete",d).append("<a><div class='prod_komplett'>"+e+a+f+c+"</div></a>").appendTo(b)}});
```

The part for position is here

```
 position:{my:"right top",at:"right-2 bottom", collision:"flip horizontal"
```

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can read more about UI Position [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Position#overview)

Propably, to get what you want, is add this code into position:

```
   position: {
             of:"#searchbox",
             offset: "-2px 0 0 0"
         }
```

in offset parameter you can set position of box

I hope this code will helps you
Greetings

Comment: Thank you very much.. I didnt see the line for offset.. cheers